# counting all rows with at least one value larger than 0 in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count the number of rows in an array that contains at least one value larger than zero. How would I go about it?

I have data in the following format, where the data is filtered by dates. Therefore it happens that some columns will become all blank, just like "sixth value" here.

| Category | first value | second value | third value | fourth value | fifth value | sixth value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |  | 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| Banana | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| Orange | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |  |
| Melon | 1 |  | 2 |  | 2 |  |

The desired outcome here would be: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
=COUNTIF(BYROW(B2:G,LAMBDA(bgx,SUM(bgx))),">0")
```

- 

[image]